# Before Installing Ubuntu on PC with SSD & HDD

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, windows-7, ssd

I am wanting to move away from Win7 to Ubuntu (no Linux experience). I have read the tutorial on installing Ubuntu, to me it assumes Ubuntu will install on one drive.

Q1. If i want a setup where the OS is on the SSD and data storage (photo's etc) on the HDD, (that is how I have it setup on Win7) is there any thing I should know before installing Ubuntu or is it possible/easier to do post installation?

Comment: are you dual booting? or are you installing on new disks

Comment: You will be *mounting* your data drive onto the filesystem. There's a setting for that that can be done at any time after the install is complete. Like riding a bicycle, it's confusing and scary the first time you try...but quite easy and safe to do after that. **Advice**: Lots of new users from Windows want the kind of setup that you do. It's familiar. However, Ubuntu does not work quite like Windows. Embrace the difference. Stick to the installer defaults -- getting fancy is how new users get into trouble.

Comment: No to dual booting.

Comment: Format the data storage on the HDD however you want (for example NTFS) and then after Ubuntu is installed configure Ubuntu to automount the data storage partition at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set up `/home` in HDD during install

You may already know what `/home` is. It is the Ubuntu equivalent of `C:\Users` in Windows. This is where users' personal files are stored.

To do this, during install, select the "*Something Else*" option.

- Here, you will see both your SSD and HDD. Your SSD will probably be called `/dev/sda` and your HDD will be called `/dev/sdb`. (This may vary. Pay attention to sizes and partitions you have created before.)
- As you said you are not going to dual boot, I am going to assume that you are OK with formatting the whole SSD. Ok then, here goes.
- **1st Partition: EFI (For separate EFI partition. This is where your UEFI boot files are stored.)**

  1. Select your SSD.
  2. Select "*Make New Partition Table*". (**IMPORTANT: This will format the entire disk. Do not do this if you have any data you want in this disk.**)
  3. Select the free space.
  4. Select "+".
  5. Partition the target SSD as follows:

     - **Size:** 650 MB
     - **Type for the new partition:** Primary
     - **Location for the new partition:** Beginning of this space
     - **Use as:** EFI (this will be listed as `/dev/sda1` efi in the partitioning tool once you create it)
- **2nd Partition: Root** (All the software you install is stored here.)

  1. Select "free space" under your target drive (in my case `/dev/sdc`).
  2. Select "*+*".
  3. Partition the target drive as follows:

     - **Size:** min. 10 GB (25+GB [recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). I have 40GB)
     - **Type for the new partition:** Primary
     - **Location for the new partition:** Beginning of this space
     - **Use as:** ext4
     - **Mount point:** Choose `/`
- **3rd Partition: Home**

  1. Select your HDD.
  2. Make free space by selecting "*-*".
  3. Select "*+*".
  4. Partition the target drive as follows:

     - **Size:** All of the drive or any size you want. (You will need to leave some space if you want to make another partition. Of course, you can always shrink `/home` partition later.)
     - **Type for the new partition:** Primary
     - **Location for the new partition:** Beginning of this space
     - **Use as:** ext4
     - **Mount point:** Choose `/home`
- **For the bootloader device, select the SSD.**

---

You could instead set up `/home` in HDD after install, but it is a bit complicated. See [this guide on How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/442101/how-to-move-your-linux-home-directory-to-another-hard-drive/) on how to do it. You can do the steps up to create a file system using GUI with Gparted (install with `sudo apt install gparted` in terminal).

## Set up HDD to automount after install

1. Format and partition your HDD using GParted (install with `sudo apt install gparted` in terminal).
2. Go to the "Disk" utility.
3. Select your HDD.
4. Select the icon with 2 cogwheels.
5. Select "*Edit Mount Options*".
6. Turn the "*User Session Defaults*" option to "*Off*".
7. Check the box "*Mount at system startup*" Make sure "*Show in the user interface*" is also checked.
8. Change the "*Mount point*" to something less complicated like */mnt/MyFiles*.
9. Click "*OK*".

Comment: Do you have to create an efi parti on?

Comment: @Peter Don't you? We are doing a something else installation...